# c++ convert infinity to max and -inf to min

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, double

How to implement the following action?

```
if( boost::math:: +is_inf (x) )
    x= max double;
else if( boost::math:: -is_inf (x) )
    x= min double;
```

I want to preserve the sign of x.

Comment: [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Comment: and how about -inf ?

Comment: @LudwigSchulze what do you mean by best?

Comment: "What is the _best_ code for the following action?"

Comment: You Started with the "best" bit - forth word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is, you can compare `+inf` or `-inf` to 0 with `<` and `>`, so testing the sign is very easy.

```
if(std::isinf(x))
{
    if(x>0)
        x = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    else
        x = -std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
}
```

No needs for boost, if you are using c++11

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is not the correct approach here.

Comment: min = 2.2250738585072014e-308

Comment: thanks. cppreference is quite wrong here : "minimum value of float, double and long double respectively". This should be "minimum non zero positive value"

Comment: @galinette, The word "normalized" is used here and there. But that entry could use some work. `numeric_limits<double>` does behaves unintuitively.

Comment: Free piece of advice - if you are prone to run into Inf, you should also strongly consider to check for NaN.

Comment: @galinette: You are quoting the C interface documentation here, specifically `FLT_MIN`/`DBL_MIN`/`LDBL_MIN`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl. Yes indeed. Unlike those macros, however, `std::numeric_limits` is the idiomatic way, and has the advantage of being useful in meta-programming.

Comment: @ChristianHackl : yes, but the documentation about numeric_limits::min redirect to these macros, so it's based on the C standard